# Changing NA to blank without changing whole vector to characters in R

Tags: r, na

```
 a = c(1, 2, 3, 4, NA, 5)
```

I want to change the NA to blank. However, if I do so using:

```
a[is.na(a)] <- ''
```

The whole vector becomes characters and I will not be able to work with them. Is there any other way to change NA to a numeric blank? Thanks!

Comment: There is no such thing as a numeric blank. `NA` is the closest thing you're going to get. *Displaying* NA values as blank when you print/render your data is a separate issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. There is no such thing as a numeric blank.